# Django ORM - filter by count of related across multiple levels

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following three models (simplified):

```py
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    pass

class Gallery(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')

class Photo(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey('Gallery')
```

On profile detail I want to show **all galleries that have at least one photo**.

I tried to go this way:

```py
Gallery.objects.all().filter(user_profile__pk=x). \
    annotate(count_photos=Count('photo_set')).filter(count_photos__gt=0)
```

But this leads to an error:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'photo_set' into field. Choices are: id, user_profile`

I understand, that `Gallery.objects.all()` is `Queryset`, so this is probably not possible. Solution could be to start from `Photo`:

```py
Photo.objects.all().filter(gallery__user_profile__pk=x)
```

But I need to iterate in template over galleries and not over photos.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this leads to the same error `Cannot resolve keyword 'photo_set' into field...`.

Comment: `Gallery.objects.filter(user_profile__id=x). \     annotate(count_photos=Count('photo__id')).filter(count_photos__gt=0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with `__id` as well as with `__pk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
 Gallery.objects.filter(user_profile__id=x)
                .annotate(count_photos=Count('photo__id'))
                .filter(count_photos__gt=0)
```

In annotate, it is not `X_set` but just `X`.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work,, Shorthand for above:

```
 Gallery.objects.filter(user_profile__id=x)
                .annotate(count_photos=Count('photo'))
                .filter(count_photos__gt=0)
```

**One more way** to Make this query:

```
 Gallery.objects.filter(user_profile__id=x, photo__isnull=False).distinct()
```